# php: converting an array of objects to pure array

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

following array is received at server side :

```
[{"id":"2","foo":"bar","children":[{"id":"4","foo":"baz","children":[{"id":"6"}]},{"id":"5"}]},{"id":"7"},{"id":"3"}]
```

is there any way to convert it to a nested array like this?

```
[
  ['id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar', 'children' =>[ 
                                            'id'=> 4, 'foo' => 'baz' ....
```

P.S: i find  out that without using any function i will have desired code format on server side. maybe this is because of sending data as post request (using ajax) that convert data to an array then serialize it and send , then on server side i have a nice array the same as what i'm looking for.Im not sure it is ralated to php or laravel or jquery !?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
    )

)
```

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: note second argument of json_decode also

Comment: it sounds weird, but why not try to keep it as a JSON string, then replace '{' with '[', '}' with ']' and ':' with '=>', and only then json_decode()? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the array in PHP, **Yes.** Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

To get the "nested array like this" in JSON, **No.** This is not how arrays in JSON are supposed to look. See the specification at [json.org](http://json.org/), it is really easy to understand.

Comment: Second part really doesn't make sense considering the input is already JSON

Comment: I know. I just wanted to make that point clear. One could of course also try just to "restructure" an array, thats why I included this.